# NVPACK android ndk gives failed to parse aapt dictionary files at the deploying process

Tags: android, android-ndk

I've been using nvidia's NVPACK for over a half year. I updated NVPACK to the last version since then I cannot deploy my native codded app to the android tablet it says Failed to query ActivityName: Failed to parse aapt dictionary values. I couldn't figure out what's wrong so couldn't fix the problem. Please help fixing this. Kind regards to all.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading Nsight Tegra to the version 1.5 fixes the problem. New Nsight Tegra update'll probably fix this issue, but for now using the older version seems to be the best solution.